# MapReduce code mpi time out

Tags: mapreduce, mpi, mpi4py

I am using a MapReduce code, and I met a problem: the code doesn't respond after the map (takes 1 hr) finished. I digged into the code and find this function doesn't respond:

```
def wait(self, running, tag): """Test if any worker has finished its job. If so, decrease its key and make it available """ 
  atimer = Timer('Wait')

  inittime = time()
  status = MPI.Status()
  while time() - inittime < self.config['jobwait']:
      if world.Iprobe(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE,tag=tag,status=status):
          jobf = world.recv(source=status.source, tag=tag)
          idx = 0
          for ii, worker in enumerate(self.workers):
              if worker.id == status.source: idx = ii; break
          if self.config['verbosity'] >= 8:
              print('Freeing worker '+str(self.workers[idx].id))
          worker = self.workers[idx]

          # faulty worker's job has already been cleaned
          if not worker.isFaulty():
              del running[jobf]
          else:
              self.nActive += 1
          worker.setFree()
          heapq._siftup(self.workers, idx)
```

This line doesn't respond :

```
if world.Iprobe(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE,tag=tag,status=status):
```

I wonder if there is a time out for `Iprobe()` in `mpi4py` and how to set the timeout time for it? Is there a alternative for `Iprobe()` that has the same role here?

Here is the previous function that send the message via .send()

```
def execTask(self, task):
    """Wrapper function calling mapping/reducing/finalizing phase tasks,
    dispatch tasks to workers until all finished and collect feedback. 
    Faulty workers are removed from active duty work list.
    """
    atimer = Timer(task)
    print( 'Entering {0:s} phase...'.format(task) )

    taskDict = { 'Map':(self.mapIn, MAP_START, MAP_FINISH), \
            'Init':(self.mapIn, INIT_START, MAP_FINISH), \
            'Reduce':(self.reduceIn, REDUCE_START, REDUCE_FINISH) }

    # line up jobs and workers into priority queues
    jobs = taskDict[task][0][:]
    heapq.heapify(jobs); running = {}
    heapq.heapify(self.workers)

    while (jobs or running) and self.nActive > 0:
        # dispatch all jobs to all free workers
        while jobs and self.workers[0].isFree():
            job = heapq.heappop(jobs)
            worker = heapq.heappop(self.workers)
            world.send(job, dest=worker.id, tag=taskDict[task][1])
            print('hi')
            print job
            worker.setBusy(); heapq.heappush(self.workers, worker)
            running[job] = (time(), worker)
            if self.config['verbosity'] >= 6:
                print('Dispatching file '+os.path.basename(job)+' to worker '+str(worker.id))
            # if no more free workers, break
            if not self.workers[0].isFree(): break

        # wait for finishing workers as well as do cleaning
        self.wait(running, taskDict[task][2])
       # print running 
        self.clean(running, jobs)

    print( '{0:s} phase completed'.format(task) )
```

The whole code can be seen here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B36fJi35SPIedWdjbW5NdzlCeTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it really just hanging on that call? It really shouldn't be doing that since `IPROBE` is a non-blocking call that doesn't require progress on the network. Are you sure it's not just spending a lot of time there and making your traces look bad? If that's the case, your issue is that the appropriate message isn't getting sent.

Comment: Yes, it hangs there and get stuck, I am sure after the map (takes 1hr) finishes, it just get stuck there, do you have any solution to this?

Comment: @WesleyBland  if it is like your saying, the message isn't getting sent, what is the solution of it?

Comment: @WesleyBland, do you have any suggestion

Comment: It probably means that you're not sending the messages. The problem is very rarely that the library is misbehaving. It's probably an issue with your code. Unfortunately, there isn't any included with the question. I'd encourage you to take a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guide for advice on how to post a good code example that isn't too long.

Comment: @WesleyBland, the code link is in the question, at the bottom

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to sift through 500 lines to find your problem. I'd encourage you to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask again. Especially the part about not dropping 500 lines of code in your question.

Comment: @WesleyBland, I put the previous function that send the message here, I print out something there, it shows the message is sent

Comment: What I'm trying to say by continuing to refer you to the guide is that you're going to have to do more work on your end to shrink down your code to just the problematic parts. Remove all the extra stuff. It doesn't matter if you get an answer or print extra debug junk. You need to create a runnable example that demonstrates your problem in <100 lines.

Comment: @WesleyBland, it is hard, the code rely on several other codes to run, would you please give me your email, we can discuss via emails